# What is a Bonjwa?

Tags: terminology, starcraft

I heard the term bonjwa used in the context of "Boxer is a Bonjwa". What is a Bonjwa and does it give any privileges to be a Bonjwa?

How can I become a Bonjwa?

Comment: A great thread about the statistics of Bonjwas throughout SC:BW history: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=357124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Bonjwa):

> Bonjwa is a term used to describe a player who dominates the StarCraft scene for a long period of time.

Appears to be a simple slang title given to great players. No privileges other than the subtle sort that accompany fame and prowess.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for the answer! We want to try to give everyone [the benefit of the doubt here when asking questions here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#benice): telling people they should've Googled is generally considered pretty hostile. I don't know about you, but I know I've thought to ask someone who I consider to be an expert before thinking to do a Google search more than once or twice. We also [try to improve posts here to be the best they can be](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), which includes fixing grammatical issues like missing pronouns.

Comment: Not disrespectful. Standard fare in the other SE-hubs I've been on.  Nothing in this.meta or the FAQ speaks against it. Issues that affect clarity should be changed; grammatical issues that do not affect clarity are below the threshold. Why did you leave alone the final sentence, which is technically a fragment (as it possesses no true verb)? If we fix every post to adhere to Strunk & White, we will sacrifice readability (particularly as what is truly a grammatical error can be quite subjective, and we reach anarchy when any unelected individual with >X rep can and will edit a post).

Comment: I totally understand where you're coming from, but here on Stack Exchange, [embracing non-Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) is part of the culture, and community editing is by design and actively encouraged: while I think it's great you're willing to contribute answers, if that's not something you're comfortable with, Stack Exchange [might not be the right place for you](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing). People actively helping to improve the site's overall quality by correcting grammar issues is something you'll run into often here.

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen that meta post. Fair enough. As far as community editing goes, however, there is an established conservatism regarding what is considered a meaningful edit, and what is not. Changing 'Appears' to 'It appears' is not meaningful.

Comment: Here on Stack Exchange, when we edit a post to fix one issue, we try to fix as many issues as possible while we're there: this way, we make posts the best the can be while minimizing the number of edits done: in this case, fixing the grammatical issue was done at the same time as removing the Google bit as well as the linkification of the source. Check out the blog post "[In Defense of Editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)", which describes Stack Exchange's editing philosophy in more detail.

Comment: Fair enough on that too, then (though, again, that doesn't address the distinction between a stylistic element that may contradict S&W but is perfectly understandable, and a true grammatical error). As a side note, your over-the-top politeness, coupled with links, come across as exceedingly condescending. I expect I'm not the only one that greets your comments with mild hostility.

Comment: I'm sorry I caused offense by my politeness and the links: my intent was not to condescend, just to help explain what happened with the editing. Stack Exchange has had a problem with people being jerks to new users, so it's something we've been trying to fix lately. Anyway, thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @ChristopherBerman I would say that correct grammar actually is quite important, especially to help people whose native language is not English understand the post easily.

Comment: @Murga: Good point. Didn't think about that